# Drag and Drop - Drag an item already dropped

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Good Morning,
I can not do this drag and drop in jscript.
After picking up the item and dropping it into the 'conteudo' div, I can not pick it up again (inside the conteudo div) and move it freely because it return an error, can somebody help me?

[image]

[image]

```js
      //Drag'n Drop functions
      function allowDrop(ev) 
      {
          ev.preventDefault();
      }

      function drag(ev) 
      {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy"; 
      }

      function drop(ev) 
      {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var x = ev.clientX;
          var y = ev.clientY;
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
          var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
          var original = document.getElementById(data);
          copyimg.src = original.src;
          ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
          copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: "+(y-50)+"px; left:"+(x-50)+"px;");
          copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      }
```

```css
    #conteudo{
      width:500px;
      height:500px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#ff1;  
      display: initial;
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <div id="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elementCounter = 0; // to assign ids to dropped element.
//Drag'n Drop functions
      function allowDrop(ev) 
      {
          ev.preventDefault();
      }

      function drag(ev) 
      {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy"; 
      }

      function drop(ev) 
      {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var x = ev.clientX;
          var y = ev.clientY;
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
          var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
          var original = document.getElementById(data);
          copyimg.src = original.src;
          ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
          if(original.parentNode.id == "conteudo"){
            original.parentNode.removeChild(original);
          }
          copyimg.id = "dropped_elem"+(++elementCounter);
          copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: "+(y-50)+"px; left:"+(x-50)+"px;");
          copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
          copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
      }
```

```css
#conteudo{
      width:500px;
      height:500px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#ff1;  
      display: initial;
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <div id="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have added below things in your code :-

1. copyimg.id = "dropped_elem"+(++elementCounter); :- to assign id to dropped element.
2. copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)"); :- so that element can be dragged again.
3. elementCounter :- variable to assign ids to dropped elements.

Comment: Inside drop function we are checking that if the dropped element's parent node id is "conteudo". If yes then we are removing the dragged eleement.

Comment: Lalit, can you help me again?

Comment: Yes, what happened?